# Implementing last file accessed time in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, file-access

Can anyone give a sample program to display the last accessed time of file which should be visible to next time file opening person

Answer (score 1):

We don't usually give sample programs, it's your job to write the program. We might help you if you get stuck writing it.

Look at the [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm) command, specifically the `atime` subcommand, which reports the latest access time for a file on systems that have support for that (Windows FAT systems don't, for instance).

Comment: In this case, a sample program would be a one liner. It could be given in such a way as to be what the questioner asked for without it being useful to them for the overall task that they were trying to get other people to do for them.